# Nhibernate error: NO row with given identifier found error

Tags: nhibernate

I know that this question is repeated one.
But no one could answer briefly enough to answer corrctly.
I am getting Nhibernate error  " No row with given identiifer found error" when im trying to use the guid to give me the record from the table.
I am using Nhibernate load function to load  the record with the unique identifier(GUID) but if the record is not there it is giving exception.
Am I missing some property in hbm.xml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html_single/#manipulatingdata-loading),

> Note that Load() will throw an unrecoverable exception if there is no matching database row.

If you want to query for a particular record and not have an exception, use an actual query or the `Get()` method.

Also from the documentation:

> If you are not certain that a matching row exists, you should use the Get() method, which hits the database immediately and returns null if there is no matching row.

So use `Get()` and check the result for null.