# Handle NHibernate Load fail

Tags: nhibernate, exception, load

I have the following method.

```
    public Foo GetById(int id)
    {
        ISession session = GetCurrentSession();
        try
        {
            return session.Load<Foo>(id);
        }
        catch(NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException onfe)
        {
            throw(onfe);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, onfe is never thrown. I want to handle the case that I only get
back a proxy because no adequate row exists in database.

Comment: Do it throws any exception at this point?

Comment: no, none at this point. when I use session.Get(), it isn´t thrown either :(

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you write your own ObjectNotFoundException and rewrite the method as:

```
public Foo GetById(int id)
{
    Foo foo;
    ISession session = GetCurrentSession();
    foo = session.Get<Foo>(id);
    if (foo == null)
    {
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException(string.Format("Foo with id '{0}' not found.", id));
    }
}
```

There are two problems with your method as written:

1. You should use `Get` to load an entity by its key.
2. Your exception handling is wrapping the original exception and re-throwing for no reason.

Comment: Can you nearer explain your statement no. 2?

Comment: Your catch block is not handling the ObjectNotFoundException, it is wrapping it in a new Exception and throwing that. The biggest problem is that calling code will only be able to catch Exception and won't know if the object failed to load or something else went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If an entity is allowed to be lazy-loaded then Load method returns uninitialized proxy. The ObjectNotFoundException is thrown as soon as the proxy is about to be initialized.

Get method should be prefered when you are not sure that a requested entity exists.

See:
[Nhibernate error: NO row with given identifier found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744150/nhibernate-error-no-row-with-given-identifier-found-error/748366#748366)
,
https://sites.google.com/a/thedevinfo.com/thedevinfo/Home/or-persistence/hibernate/hibernate-faq, etc...